# How to groupby join rows while ignoring None values in columns?

Tags: python, pandas

I've a dataframe like below,

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([['a', 'a', 'b', 'b'], [1, 1, 2, 2], 
                            ['k', 'l', 'm', 'n']]).T, 
                  columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])

df = df.groupby(['a'])['b', 'c'].agg(','.join)

print(df)

     b     c
a       
a   1,1   k,l
b   2,2   m,n
```

But when I add a None value to the original dataframe the same agg func return different result, i.e..

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([['a', 'a', 'b', 'b'], [1, 1, 2, 2], 
                            ['k', 'l', 'm', None]]).T, 
                  columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])

df = df.groupby(['a'])['b', 'c'].agg(','.join)

print(df)

      b       c
a       
a   a,b,c   a,b,c
b   a,b,c   a,b,c
```

For the second dataframe i.e with None value in a row I'm looking for this below desired output:

```
     b     c
a       
a   1,1   k,l
b   2,2   m
```

Comment: Try replace None with np.nan or ' '. Pandas does not work well with None.

Comment: Could you insert `''` instead of `None`? result is `m,` when utilizing `''` over `None`

Comment: @jasonwong I tried it but still it didn't got me the desired output.

Comment: @user_12 _I tried it_ Please share exactly what you changed, and what happened.

Comment: Could you also explain what that operation is meant to do in the first place? It seems somewhat unusual.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may also use `dropna` within lambda. Just in case you dataframe has any non-string column, you should chain additional `.astype(str)` after `dropna`. If you are sure all your columns values are strings, you just skip the `.astype(str)` part

```
df_join = df.groupby('a').agg(lambda x: ','.join(x.dropna().astype(str)))

Out[809]:
     b    c
a
a  1,1  k,l
b  2,2    m
```

---

A little faster solution is using python `filter` to filter out `None` and `map` to convert to string before `join`. As I say it is a little faster on big dataframe, but the trade off is less readable

```
df_join = df.groupby('a').agg(lambda x: ','.join(map(str, filter(None,x))))

Out[823]:
     b    c
a
a  1,1  k,l
b  2,2    m
```

Answer (score 1):

One way using `lambda` to filter `None`:

```
df = df.groupby('a').agg(lambda x: ','.join(str(i) for i in x if i is not None))
print(df)
```

Output:

```
     b    c
a          
a  1,1  k,l
b  2,2    m
```

Comment: Thank you. Is it scalable because I'm dealing with huge dataset. Performance is kinda important in my case.

Answer (score 0):

another approach is using the:
    `more_itertools.chunked(iterable, n)`
method on:
https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#grouping

Answer (score 0):

I modified from the comment above and test it, now it works:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([['a', 'a', 'b', 'b'], [1, 1, 2, 2], 
                            ['k', 'l', 'm', None]]).T, 
                  columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])
df = df.replace([None], '')
df.b = df.b.astype('str')
df = df.groupby(['a'])['b', 'c'].agg(lambda x:','.join(x).rstrip(','))
print(df)
```

output:

```
     b    c
a          
a  1,1  k,l
b  2,2    m
```